# Please help I am having a problem with 4 lines html css code

Tags: html, css

Why is the button smaller than the search box?

```css
.class1{
height:50px;
}
.class2{
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
Why is the button smaller than the search box?

<input type="text"class="class1">
<input type="submit"class="class2">
```

Why is the button smaller than the search box?

Comment: on my device (firefox desktop) the button appear bigger then than search box.

Comment: different browser has different layout by default, if you want absolute control over the appearance, don't leave the width, height, margin, padding, and border unspecified. Or, consider to use an UI framework like material design button / ionic button / bootstrap button

Comment: Can you assign an example where the button and the search box are the same size?

Comment: Does this appear to have same height on your device? https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-black-gv3it

Comment: answer will be use box-sizing:border-box; thanks help.